# Start Waves node com extension com.wavesplatform.dex.Matcher

Tags: java, wavesplatform

I can't run Fullnode Waves with com.wavesplatform.dex.Matcher extension

Git: https://github.com/wavesplatform/dex#7-configuration

Config File waves.conf

```
waves{
  extensions = ["com.wavesplatform.dex.Matcher"]

  dex {
    # Matcher's account address
    # account = ""

    # Matcher REST API bind address
    bind-address = "127.0.0.1"

    # Matcher REST API port
    port = 6886
  }
}
```

```
F:\DMX\Compilados\waves>java -cp "F:\ZZZ\Compilados\waves\waves-all-1.1.5.jar;F:\ZZZ\Compilados\waves\lib\*" com.wavesplatform.Application waves.conf
2019-11-14 15:44:34,305 INFO  [main] c.w.Application$ - Starting...
2019-11-14 15:44:35,213 INFO  [ctor.default-dispatcher-3] a.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
2019-11-14 15:44:35,395 INFO  [main] c.w.Application$ - Waves v1.1.5 Blockchain Id: L
2019-11-14 15:44:38,473 INFO  [main] c.w.n.PeerDatabaseImpl - Loaded 0 known peer(s) from peers.dat
2019-11-14 15:44:39,026 INFO  [main] com.wavesplatform.package$ - Genesis block Block(5VRm8QtPbZ11SZfdkUKUZGSKbACyyhFuKUAzKLxpNQowhxbHbSx1wsS3jf3cM3WMa5x8XdmoLcRr2JrsHNmMpXkv -> 67rpwLC..., txs=2, features=Set()) has been added to the state
2019-11-14 15:44:39,497 INFO  [main] c.w.Application - Enable extension: com.wavesplatform.dex.Matcher
2019-11-14 15:44:39,566 ERROR [main] c.w.actor.RootActorSystem$ - Error while initializing actor system wavesplatform
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.wavesplatform.Application.$anonfun$run$15(Application.scala:248)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
        at com.wavesplatform.Application.run(Application.scala:244)
        at com.wavesplatform.Application$.$anonfun$startNode$4(Application.scala:495)
        at com.wavesplatform.Application$.$anonfun$startNode$4$adapted(Application.scala:475)
        at com.wavesplatform.actor.RootActorSystem$.start(RootActorSystem.scala:25)
        at com.wavesplatform.Application$.startNode(Application.scala:475)
        at com.wavesplatform.Application$.main(Application.scala:458)
        at com.wavesplatform.Application.main(Application.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: InvalidAddress(Wrong addressBytes length: expected: 26, actual: 0)
        at com.wavesplatform.common.utils.package$EitherExt2.explicitGet(package.scala:20)
        at com.wavesplatform.dex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.scala:48)
        ... 22 common frames omitted

F:\DMX\Compilados\waves>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

> 2019-11-14 15:44:39,566 ERROR [main] c.w.actor.RootActorSystem$ -
>   Error while initializing actor system wavesplatform
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null

Answer (score 1):

The cause is:

```
InvalidAddress(Wrong addressBytes length: expected: 26, actual: 0)
```

Because in the old versions of Matcher you had specify address of node which will be used for Matcher:

```
dex {
  account = "" # must be specified!
```

But now Matcher configuration is simplified:

```
waves.extensions += "com.wavesplatform.dex.grpc.integration.DEXExtension"
waves.dex {
  grpc.integration {
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 6887
  }
}
```

Please see details in the official GitHub repository:
https://github.com/wavesplatform/dex#-configration-of-dex-extension